# How do you use the StateT Monad Transformers in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, state-monad

Given a simple list

```
newtype SomeList = SomeList { items :: [SomeItem] }
```

and a helper function

```
newtype SomeListStateT a = SomeListStateT 
  { runSomeListStateT :: StateT SomeList IO a 
  } deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO)
```

Can anyone provide a simple example of how to construct a StateT monad transformer to perform CRUD operations against the list please?

I want to add and modify items through Strict State Monad actions.

Unfortunately, the documentation is not so easy to follow ([https://docs.w3cub.com/haskell~8/libraries/transformers-0.5.6.2/control-monad-trans-state-strict#g:2](https://docs.w3cub.com/haskell%7E8/libraries/transformers-0.5.6.2/control-monad-trans-state-strict#g:2))

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: https://wiki.haskell.org/Simple_StateT_use has some simple examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a lot of this information through GHCi. That is, if you happen to know the various incantations and how to interpret them. Let's start with `MonadState`:

```
ghci> :m + Control.Monad.State
ghci> :i MonadState
type MonadState :: * -> (* -> *) -> Constraint
class Monad m => MonadState s m | m -> s where
  get :: m s
  put :: s -> m ()
  state :: (s -> (a, s)) -> m a
  {-# MINIMAL state | get, put #-}
    -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.State.Class’
instance [safe] Monad m => MonadState s (StateT s m)
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.State.Class’
```

Ignoring the missing instance for your type for now, we can see that `MonadState` defines three operations (the CRUD-operations if you will). We can further see that `StateT` has an instance of `MonadState`. This means that we can specialise e.g. `get`:

```
ghci> :t get @_ @(StateT _ _)
get @_ @(StateT _ _) :: Monad _1 => StateT _2 _1 _2
```

So we require that the second parameter to `StateT` must be a monad. This of course matches the instance we saw above. Now you chose to write a `newtype`-wrapper around `StateT SomeList IO` which means that you don't have a `MonadState` instance. You could solve this in two ways:

1. Use a type synonym in stead of a `newtype`
2. Implement an instance. You can derive such an instance with `-XGeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`

Assuming you create an instance `instance MonadState SomeList SomeListStateT` you would then see that the three functions specialise to:

```
ghci> :t get @_ @SomeListStateT
get @_ @SomeListStateT :: SomeListStateT SomeList
ghci> :t put @_ @SomeListStateT
put @_ @SomeListStateT :: SomeList -> SomeListStateT ()
ghci> :t state @_ @SomeListStateT
state @_ @SomeListStateT
  :: (SomeList -> (a, SomeList)) -> SomeListStateT a
```

If you want to retain your newtype wrapper, you should consider writing a function analogous to:

```
ghci> :t runStateT
runStateT :: StateT s m a -> s -> m (a, s)
```

But with the type

```
SomeListStateT a -> SomeList -> IO (a, SomeList)
```

Comment: get and put has a type mismatch, i dont know how to unwrap my `newtype SomeListStateT a = SomeListStateT `  on calling evalState get

Comment: Hint: What's the type of `runSomeListStateT`?

Comment: haha yes i get that but ive tried multiple things to match the specialized get and put monadic actions but i cant get it working...
`addItem :: SomeItem -> SomeListStateT Int  
addItem item = do  
  let state = evalState get []  
  let list = items (SomeList state) ++ [item]  
  let someList = SomeList { items = list }  
  let newstate = SomeListStateT { runSomeListStateT = someList }  
  execState put newstate  
  return (length list) `

Comment: this is the instance i have declared...
`class SomeListMonad m where
  add    :: SomeItem -> m Int

instance SomeListMonad SomeListStateT where
  add = addItem`

Comment: `state` allows you to "lift" a stateful function into a state monad. You probably dont want to be running `evalState` in `addItem`.
`addItem :: MonadState [a] m => a -> m ()`

`addItem x = state (\xs -> ((), x : xs))`